# SQL Server 2012 Adding/Subtracting Values in Hierarchy with Function

Tags: sql-server, function, recursion, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have a Problem evaluating my hierarchial data and would be very pleased, if any of you had a tip.

My table has 4 columns: `ID` is self explanatory, `parentID` creates the hierarchy and there is only one parent for each child, `value` is just a numeric value of currency (some rows will have NULL as their Value) and finally `operator` which is a bit that can be 3 Values `0, 1 and NULL` (I want to it correspond to `-, + and ignore` but more about that later). Operator directly discloses the operator with which the child is related to its parent.

E.g. `ID, ParentID, Operator, Value` `23, 2, 1, 2.22` has the operator 1 and thus shall be added when trying to calculate the value of its parent with`ID = 2`

The purpose of my function will be to calculate the `value` of a given `ID` by recursively checking for all the children and if the `operator` is `1` *adding* or if it is `0` *subtracting* the value from the total (if it is `NULL` the value will be ignored).

So far I had written a function with a recursive **cte** that finds all children and sub-children of a given `ID` gathers them together in one table and then takes the sum after applying a `case`.

```
function [dbo].[total](
@id int)
returns NUMERIC(20,2)
AS
BEGIN
declare @total numeric(20,2);

cte as(
SELECT id, parentid, operator, value, 0 as level
    FROM data
    WHERE pos = @pos
    union all
 select t.id, t.parentid, t.operator, t.value, c.level + 1
 FROM
    data t
 inner join cte c on c.id = t.parentid)

 SELECT @total = (select sum (case when operator = 0 then (5 * value) when operator = 1 then value/100 else 0 end) from cte);
RETURN @total
END
```

This function works to some extend e.g. `dbo.total(1)` would give me the correct result of 1 `-2.5+3.5` in this example.

```
ID       Operator  Value  ParentID
1        1         NULL    -
 2       1         NULL    1
  3      0         2.5     2
  4      1         3.5     2
```

In other cases however this doesn't work as well. In this example it would return a value of `5 + 2.5 + 2.5 = 10` even though I would want it to "recognize" that the parent of `3` and `4` (`2`) has an operator of 0 and thus their values should be subtracted, resulting in a different calculation `5 - (2.5 + 2.5) = 0`

```
ID       Operator  Value  ParentID
1        1         5    -
 2       0         NULL    1
  3      1         2.5     2
  4      1         2.5     2
```

I hope i am not the first one facing this problem and am looking forward to any answers that you might have on this topic. Should you have questions, feel free to ask me. :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did u get the result? @kacase

Comment: not yet i am still working on it @SarathAvanavu

Comment: @SarathAvanavu now i got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to work around this problem. I am still using the same CTE. I just added a `WHILE` loop so i could work my way up from the "youngest" child to the oldest (min level to max level)

This is how it now works:

```
function [dbo].[total](@id int)
returns NUMERIC(20,2)
AS
BEGIN
declare @total numeric(20,2);
declare @level int;
declare @cte table (id int, parentid int,operator bit,value numeric(20,2),level int);

--the same cte that i had used earlier
cte as
(SELECT id, parentid, operator, value, 0 as level
    FROM
    data
    WHERE id = @id
union all
select t.id, t.parentid, t.operator, t.value, c.level + 1
FROM
    data t
inner join cte c on c.id = t.parentid
)

--write the calculated cte to @cte
insert into @cte select * from cte


--This is where the magic happens. The while loop uses the fact that all
children were given a level higher than 0 in the cte.
While (select max(level) from @cte)>0
BEGIN
select @level = max(level) from @cte
UPDATE @cte
SET value = t.summe

from @cte AS ctable inner join(
SELECT parentid, sum(case when dtable.operator = 0 then (-1 * dtable.value)
when dtable.operator = 1 then dtable.value else 0 end) summe
FROM @cte dtable
group by parentid
)
as t
on t.parentid = ctable.id
WHERE level = @level -1


--delete the rows, with the current max level.
This causes the loop to work and acts like an i-- for my while function
DELETE  @cte
FROM @cte ctable
WHERE ctable.level = @level

END


SELECT @total = (select sum (value) from @cte);
RETURN @total
END
```